# Google Datastore - Whats the concurrent read/ write per second

Tags: concurrency, google-cloud-datastore

We are running load tests for GCP Datastore, and when we approach 100 concurrent users, the average duration for a read/ write operations goes up to above 10s. We wonder if there is any limit on the concurrent read or write for Datastore?

Also, is there any info about the IOPS for datastore?

Any info on optimizing the concurrent reads for datastore is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [Datastore How To guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/how-to)s may be of some help here.

Datastore scaling and performance is based on how it is used.  For example, individual entity groups only perform well if the write rate to them is fewer than once per second.  Writes from multiple sources to a single entity group will contend with each other.

To give some flavor, if you were reading/writing to each of 1 million entities with their own entity group once per second Datastore would be fine.  Writing 1 million times per second to a single entity won't work because of the entity group write rate limits.

If you are having issues as your user count goes up it is probably because you have inadvertently introduced contention around an entity group somewhere. Reduce the write rate to the entity group and the problems will probably go away.